# How to quickly develop a sortable, paged data grid of a MySQL table in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, datagrid

How do I quickly develop a sortable, paged data grid of a MySQL table in PHP/JavaScript?

If the grid could sort/page and download data via AJAX it would work better, of course :)

I could develop it manually using AJAX to update the datagrid on sort/page navigation, but I was wondering if any datagrid components already existing that would do the same.

I've never used a PHP framework before so if you recommend one I'd appreciate some help in getting started configuring/using its features to get a MySQL table outputted as a datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few PHP/Javascript solutions that show datagrids of MySQL tables:

**jqGrid** is a grid component for ASP.NET & PHP, that supports row editing, sorting, paging, searching and even nested grids!

[site](http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx)

- Client-side javascript based on jQuery
- Theming based on jQuery UI (Themeroller)
- Support for all major databases (MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL)

**SlickGrid** is an unlimited-scrolling grid component that supports sorting, and editors per column type, such as Checkboxes, Dates, Progress bars, etc.

[blog entry](http://blogfreakz.com/javascript/slickgrid-fast-rendering-javascript-gridspreadsheet-component/)

**Ext.ux.Livegrid** is a grid component that connects to a database backend and renders large sets of data into a grid, without the need of paging.

[site](http://www.ext-livegrid.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of jQuery based solutions for sortable datagrids with AJAX support. Just do some googling for them.

For example:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck with the YUI DataTable:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/

You can use it in almost any mode you want, but I prefer loading data over AJAX, as you suggested.  It is quite good at doing this, and works effectively on any browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several different datagrid solutions, but I found them all somewhat cumbersome to work with. So I created an open source project that very easily converts ***any*** MySQL SELECT statement into a searchable, sortable, paginated datagrid: http://mysqlgrid.com or on Github: https://github.com/escalibore/mySqlGrid

I hope you find it useful!